# Trying to save Gif in photoshop, but saves frames as separate images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, jpg

Trying to save Gif in photoshop, but saves frames as separate images? When I click the file it doesn't save as an animated gif.. help?

I do File > Export > Save for web > Make sure it's a gif > Save > Images only and Default

Comment: Care to show us screenshot(s) of what you're doing?  It sounds right, so I'm curious if there's something else going on

Comment: Did you check the "Animation" option in the save for web dialog?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem.

If you're using a Mac OS the problem may not be how you're exporting the GIF (you're doing it correctly) but how the computer opens it.

Try either one of these:

- Open with > Web Browser
- Long pressing space bar with the gif selected